# Ploting raster data with multiple layers

Tags: r, dictionary, raster

I need to creat one figure with several raster layers. These layers are binary data (0 and 1), while some layers only have one value (0 or 1). For these layers with only one value, the figure cannot display correctly.

For example, in the below figure. Layer 3 should be in Green.
[image]

#

```
r1 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r1[] <- sample(c(0,1),100,replace=TRUE)

tst <- ratify(r1[[1]])
rat <- levels(tst)[[1]]
rat$legend <- c("Absence","Presence")
levels(tst) <- rat

r1 <- ratify(r1)
levels(r1) <- rat

r2 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r2[] <- 0
r2 <- ratify(r2)
levels(r2) <- rat

r3 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r3[] <- 1
r3 <- ratify(r3)
levels(r3) <- rat

r4 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r4[] <- sample(c(0,1),100,replace=TRUE)
r4 <- ratify(r4)
levels(r4) <- rat

r <- stack(r1,r2,r3,r4)
library(rasterVis)
levelplot(r,col.regions=c("grey","darkgreen"))
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error on my machine (Linux, R 3.1). After executing your code, layer 2 is grey and layer 3 is darkgreen - as expected. Perhaps you can try to add `zlim=c(0,1)` to your `levelplot` call.

Comment: I think you are using an old version of rasterVis. This problem was fixed recently. Could you try to update the package?

Comment: Thanks @koekenbakker I updated the R version from R 3.0.2 to R 3.1, and the packages "raster" and "rasterVis". It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the R version from R 3.0.2 to R 3.1, and the packages "raster" and "rasterVis". It works now.